# Hide/Change Report Viewer toolbar buttons in 'Angular' Telerik Report Viewer

Tags: angular, telerik-reporting

How do I remove the navigation from angular telerik report viewer?
I just want to just display the report not the toolbar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0jYA.png